# Powerpoint Slides from Remote Host

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, remote, projector

Here is my problem:

I want to display "slides" from a projector but I will not be in the same region as the projector. Can you please suggest solutions that would allow me to amend a slideshow (results will be updating periodically)from "the room next door"?

I am thinking:

1. Maybe a wifi projector could be a solution (signal strength could be an issue though)
2. Swap out Flash memory drives from a projector (not very graceful).
3. Use a laptop in both locations and use wifi between them??

Any other solutions would be welcome.

GF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these:
http://www.blackbox.com/Store/Detail.aspx/VGA-Source-Balun-Male/AC640A

Basically, you need a sender and receiver and you can then run STP (Cat5 for example generally works...) from your machine where ever to the other room

Wireless solutions do exist!
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815158342

There are more, you will need to ensure you have a transceiver and a receiver.

For the USB method, I don't know that I would try even if it existed if you can't remotely manage it, and that would require the projector have some sort of operating system robust enough for remote management and would likely get way to expensive way to fast.

Comment: I am actually trying to avoid running cables - hence I am asking about a wifi projector (if that's possible) or using flash memory drives in a projector.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see anything in the original post about not wanting to use any wire. Almost every office or presentation area has cable run for network, so I assumed it plausible. That said, I will post another alternative in a second

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend you [Prezi](http://prezi.com/)

It is a great solution to make an amazing Slide presentation about anything and it's all in the Cloud.

Also you can present to a lot of people while they see the presentation along with you while you present.

It can be edited in teams and a lot of great stuff.

Also, you can import your .ppd slides or any power point extension file you have.

I think prezi is a great solution for your needs

Hope this helps!

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem either. Software is not the problem.It's a network problem.

Comment: would it helps if you get a mobile internet service?